# Calculating "Reliability" of Cricket Stats

Tags: statistics

I'm not a statistician so please forgive the (mis)use of terminology.

I am calculating strike rates for batsmen in cricket. For non-cricket fans, this is the number of runs scored (broadly the same as points in other sports) per 100 balls faced.

So if a batsman has faced 100 balls in his career and scored 150 runs his striker rate would be 150 (runs/balls*100).

I now want to calculate how likely it is that the stat is an accurate representation of the batsman's ability.

The more balls batsmen have faced the more likely it is that the resulting stat is accurate but how do I calculate how reliable it is?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a point estimate, and a confidence interval can help you quantify your uncertainty. For your example of 150 runs in 100 balls, is there a certain number of balls per run? If so, you can definitely create a confidence interval using the standard formula and choose your level of confidence.

E.g. X bar +/- t_{99, 1-alpha/2} s/sqrt(n) is a 1-alpha/2 level confidence interval for the average hits per ball

Multiplying by 100 gives a CI for the average hits per 100 balls

Unfortunately, if you have no other information than the aggregate 150 runs in 100 balls, there is not much you can do